# How to fix 'cannot find symbol variable MyWebViewClient'

Tags: java, android

I'm getting `error: cannot find symbol variable MyWebViewClient`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    @SuppressLint("JavascriptInterface")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView.loadUrl("https://*********.com"); //Just removed for security
        WebSettings ws = myWebView.getSettings();
        ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(MyWebViewClient);


        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

and my `MyWebViewClient` class

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("https://*********.com")) {
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        return true;
    }
}
```

(Imported all necessary header files as instructed by Android-studio)
But I'm getting `error: cannot find symbol variable MyWebViewClient`.

Please someone help me.

Comment: myWebView.setWebViewClient(MyWebViewClient); was this supposed to be: myWebView.setWebViewClient(myWebView); ?

Comment: I tried I'm getting:                                                                         setWebViewClient
(android.webkit.WebViewClient)
in WebView cannot be applied
to
(android.webkit.WebView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pass your `MyWebViewClient` class as an instance in this line :

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(MyWebViewClient);
```

maybe try something like this :

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

or

```
MyWebViewClient myWebviewClientInstance = new MyWebViewClient();
myWebView.setWebViewClient(myWebviewClientInstance);
```

Comment: Thank You it worked. ( I tried myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient()); )